# SQL : get number of user but order date

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

I trying to get how many user i got in a precise day compared to the first order
for exemple :

```
"2020-02" = 20, "2020-03" = 20 ... etc...
```

I did an sql query like that :

```
SELECT o.order_id, u.id as userId, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.order_created),'%Y-%m'), COUNT(u.id) as userCount
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN order_product o ON o.order_user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

but with this query i have something like this exemple:

```
"2020-02" = 2, "2020-02" = 9, "2020-03" = 5, "2020-03" = 7
```

so i tried to `group by` `u.id` and `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.order_created),'%Y-%m')` like this exemple :

```
SELECT o.order_id, u.id as userId, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.order_created),'%Y-%m'), COUNT(u.id) as userCount
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN order_product o ON o.order_user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.order_created),'%Y-%m');
```

but it still does not work and in the 2 case, the result of the 'userCount' is not good.

So my question is, how can i get a number of users in grouped in specific month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you are asking for a pretty simple aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.order_created), '%Y-%m') as yyyymm, 
       COUNT(*) as num_orders,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.order_user_id) as num_users
FROM users u
GROUP BY yyyymm;
```

I'm a bit baffled why you are joining `order_products` when that table is not being used.  And the join conditions also don't make sense.

Comment: Thank you, i think its good, i will do more tests after. the LEFT JOIN was to get the order of user. in my exemple i did not add all my query, i use a 'where' to get specific user